# disk space wrongly displayed after installing LVM disk

Tags: disk-usage, lvm, fdisk, df

I installed ubuntu server using LVM partitioning on a 1 TB hard disk. However, after installation, i can only see 10 Gig space
here is the fidsk output

```
`
 # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00041507

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          10       71680   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              10      121602   976689152   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/dm-0: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/dm-1: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 261 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
You have new mail in /var/mail/root

and df -h output 

df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-root
                      9.9G  6.6G  2.8G  71% /
devtmpfs              1.9G  232K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              68M   22M   43M  34% /boot
tmpfs                 6.0G     0  6.0G   0% /var/spool/asterisk/monitor
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

`

any way to increase this space without reisntalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently only allocated 10gb to your root fs.  You can use `pvs` to see how much space lvm has allocated to volumes, and how much it has left, and `lvextend` to increase the size of a logical volume ( does not need to be unmounted ).  After increasing the size of the logical volume, you will need to tell the fs to use the new space.  Assuming you are using ext[234], you can do this with `resize2fs`, which also can expand without unmounting.

```
sudo lvextend -L 20g system/root
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/system-root
```

Note that expanding the volume to use ALL of the unallocated space may not be such a great idea, since you won't have any left to add new volumes later, should you choose to do so, or make use of lvm snapshots.  You can reduce the size of the volume later to free up some space, but that requires the fs to be unmounted, thus you will need to boot the server from some other medium.

Comment: excellent. it was just so easy! thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

In all seriousness, have you rebooted? This will cause the filesystem to recalculate how big it should be. There is a command to do this live, but I can't remember what it is right now.

Comment: No, it doesn't.